# Why the F-Droid repository doesn't show latest version of Firefox to download?

Tags: browser, firefox-for-android, open-source, f-droid

The latest version of Firefox available for download is v50.0 but on Play Store v52.0 is available.. Why F-droid doesn't show latest version?

Firefox (Browse the web) - https://f-droid.org/app/org.mozilla.firefox

https://f-droid.org/wiki/page/org.mozilla.firefox

Comment: At the moment the question is rather: "When will F-Droid be updated again at all?" Updates are currently stalled. Last update was more than 10 days ago – since then, not a single app was updated there. Apart from that, this question is rather better asked at the F-Droid team, as we here can only speculate. There are other apps with the same issue; often updates for a specific app stop because the dev started including non-free components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

F-Droid doesn't include Firefox anymore (*) but some builds from Firefox code, such as Fennec and Icecat.

(*) It is due some privacy concerns, Tracking, UpstreamNonFree and Non-free Addons

At the moment
**Icecat 52.4.1**

**Fennec 56.0**
Version code: 560020,560010,560000 
Current scheme: XYZAR, where X.Y.Z is upstream version, A is architecture (0 = ARMv7, 1 = x86, 2 = ARMv8), R is revision (if we need to re-release)

Answer (score 0):

Fdroid hosts an application called [FFUpdater](https://f-droid.org/packages/de.marmaro.krt.ffupdater/), which automatically detects and downloads the latest version for your device. I have used it a few times and it works on most new devices.

However, on old Android devices (4x), I found that the latest APK that it downloads is not installable.